# 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' while pasing a dataframe column to CountVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am trying to make a bag of words from using

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count = CountVectorizer()
bag = count.fit_transform(df['review'])
```

but i get this [AttributeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diso9.png)

this is the content of the column, a list of tokenized words

```
df['review'].head()

--output--
0    [gt, played, as, german, reichgt, declare, war...
1                                                [yes]
2    [very, good, game, although, a, bit, overprice...
3    [out, of, all, the, reviews, i, wrote, this, o...
4    [disclaimer, i, survivor, main, i, play, games...
Name: review, dtype: object
```

Comment: If you read [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), the input is expected to be "a sequence of items that can be of type string or byte". You gave it a sequence of lists.

Comment: i see... so is there a way i could countvectorize all the column?